# Why doesn't EnumerableRowCollection<DataRow>.Select() compile like this?

Tags: c#, linq, select, extension-methods, linq-to-dataset

This works:

```
from x in table.AsEnumerable()
where x.Field<string>("something") == "value"
select x.Field<decimal>("decimalfield");
```

but, this does not:

```
from x in table.AsEnumerable()
.Where(y=>y.Field<string>("something") == "value")
.Select(y=>y.Field<decimal>("decimalfield"));
```

I also tried:

```
from x in table.AsEnumerable()
.Where(y=>y.Field<string>("something") == "value")
.Select(y=>new { name = y.Field<decimal>("decimalfield") });
```

Looking at the two overloads of the .Select() method, I thought the latter two should both return EnumerableRowCollection, but apparently I am wrong. What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is you're combining two ways of performing a linq query (query syntax and calling the linq extension methods directly). The line `from x in table.AsEnumerable()` is not a valid query since it require at least a `select ...`. This should work:

```
table.AsEnumerable() 
.Where(y=>y.Field<string>("something") == "value") 
.Select(y=>new { name = y.Field<decimal>("decimalfield") });
```

Comment: Just to add to this... you're filtering table for 'x', but not selecting anything for it... you could keep the same syntax and just add 'select x' at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the problem is somewhere else. This compiles just fine:

```
using System.Data;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var dt = new DataTable();

        var res = from x in dt.AsEnumerable()
                  where x.Field<string>("something") == "value"
                  select x.Field<decimal>("decimalfield");

        var res2 = dt.AsEnumerable()
            .Where(y => y.Field<string>("something") == "value")
            .Select(y => y.Field<decimal>("decimalfield"));
    }
}
```

Comment: your res2 is not identical to mine. Lee's answer is the solution. i incorrectly used a "from x" when using method syntax in the latter two examples. which, coincidentally, you did not :)